# Splitting a table into groups - PHP and MYSQL

Tags: c#, php, mysql

The table name is racecard. Today, there are 9 races.

The table structure looks like this:

**RaceNo HorseNo  HorseName**

```
1   1   FAJR 
1   2   CUT DIAMOND 
1   3   VOICE OF FAITH 
1   4   CEASARINA 
1   5   JAIPUR GEM 
1   6   KATNISS 
1   7   PLAN B 
1   8   CLASSY DANCER 
1   9   RAJASTHAN GLORY 
1   10  HIGHWAY EXPRESS 
1   11  TAJ E SHAHI 
2   1   VICTORIOUS MARCH 
2   2   DEMONSTRATOR 
2   3   MYLA ROSE 
2   4   RIO 
2   5   MONZA 
3   1   TITLEIST 
3   2   SUNTAN BEAUTY 
3   3   VICTORIAN 
3   4   LAURUS PRIDE
```

...

I am trying to create a PHP page in that the entire table is grouped by race no.

The page should have the sub-headings like Race No -1, Race No - 2:

**Race No: 1**

**HorseNo Horse Name                Win bet         Show bet         Place bet**

```
1   FAJR                          textbox         textbox          textbox 

2   CUT DIAMOND                   textbox         textbox          textbox 

3   VOICE OF FAITH                textbox         textbox          textbox 

4   CEASARINA                     textbox         textbox          textbox 

5   JAIPUR GEM                    textbox         textbox          textbox 

6   KATNISS                       textbox         textbox          textbox 

7   PLAN B                        textbox         textbox          textbox 

8   CLASSY DANCER                 textbox         textbox          textbox 

9   RAJASTHAN GLORY               textbox         textbox          textbox 

10  HIGHWAY EXPRESS               textbox         textbox          textbox 

11  TAJ E SHAHI                   textbox         textbox          textbox
```

**Race No: 2**

**HorseNo Horse Name                    Win bet         Show bet         Place bet**

```
1   VICTORIOUS MARCH              textbox         textbox          textbox

2   DEMONSTRATOR                  textbox         textbox          textbox

3   MYLA ROSE                     textbox         textbox          textbox

4   RIO                           textbox         textbox          textbox

5   MONZA                         textbox         textbox          textbox
```

and so on. Also, there should be columns with text boxes for entering the bet amounts. When the user submits the form, the betting details should be stored in the betting table with respective race no, horse no and bet amount. I need to use array. Please help me in coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first determine the highest RaceNo.

```
SELECT RaceNo AS RaceNoMAX FROM racecard WHERE RaceNo=max(RaceNo)
```

then make a for or a while loop with a function to draw the table

```
While ($i<RaceNoMAX ){
   $sql = "SELECT HorseNo, Horse Name, Win_bet, Show_bet, Place_bet 
   FROM racecard 
   WHERE RaceNo=$i ORDER BY HorseNo ASC";

$result = ...;

$php_function_to_draw_the_table = ...;

$++;

}
```

Comment: "SELECT max(RaceNo) AS RaceNoMAX FROM racecard" Will this work?

Comment: I do not think so, because you must set the condition, in this case to be mac() in the WHERE clause, not in the (to be selected) fields clause

Answer (score 0):

You should create a second table race with the race number and probably additional data to a race (has it a time? Has it a name?).

```
CREATE TABLE RACE (id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key, name varchar(255));
```

Everytime you add a new race, you just insert into that table:

```
INSERT INTO race (name) value ("afternoonrace");
```

Then you get the id for that race in php (it is easy to find for C#):

```
$raceId = last_insert_id
```

and then into the racecard

```
INSERT INTO racecard (raceNo, horseNo, horseName) values ($raceId, 12, "Harald");
```

Now for your Question:

```
$stmt = " select id, name from race";
```

gives the races. Use your favorite Query executor to get a Resultset `$rs`. Don't use mysql_query, it gives bad Karma - I mean it's obsolete.

```
while($raceRow =  $rs->next()){
    $raceId = $raceRow['id'];
    $raceName = $raceRow['name'];

    $cardStmt = " select * from racecard where race = $raceId";
    $cardRs = mysqli_query($con, $cardStmt);
    print("<h2>Race $raceName</h2>");
    while($cardRow = $cardRs->next()){
        print(makeRow($cardRow));
    }
}
```

Think about a table for the horses too. I mean, a horse should be worth a table, shouldn't it? ;-)

Comment: Yes, there are names for the race events. Example: Governor's cup, Champion's Trophy... I'll follow your suggestion: First I'll create the RACE table with RaceNo, RaceName, RaceTime... with RaceNo as primary key. Then create a dependent table RACECARD with HorseNo, HorseName, RaceNo.

Comment: OK, I hope the programming was fun! If one or two of the answers were helpful, it would be nice to upvote them and mark one as the solution.

Comment: Yes. Great feeling. Enjoyed. Thanks to stackoverflow.com. Very helpful  knowledge base.